# My C# with MySql backend database code runs well in VS 2019, but after compile, executable will breaks on first query

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout, executable

and throws an exception. And it wasn't like this just a day ago. Can someone give me a clue as to where and what to look for the bug? Thanks.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTo3s.png)

Comment: Does it work 2nd time?  Sound like the old connection was used with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Try put breakpoints, and check variables on each step.
Also, some code can help.